# Do these comment stickers from Pixiv come from anime?

Tags: pixiv

In Pixiv, you can leave a comment on any fan-art. There is also an option to leave a sticker for comment. They include an elephant, fox (?), girls, and skull.

[image: Pixiv Sticker]

[Here is a fan-art example from one of those stickers](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=42168307). I've tried to google the tag but couldn't find anything.

[image: Pixiv Sticker 2]

I'm asking about all the stickers - elephant, fox (?), girls, and skull - , but more specifically, the one for [these girls above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FswIi.jpg). Do these stickers come from an anime? If so, which one? If they are original characters, do they have any names?

Comment: with pixiv being a site for creators, I would guess it's artistic work by either its users or staff

Comment: I'd say perhaps "anime inspired" but not "from a specific anime."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They are original characters for pixiv, not from any anime.**

Based from the [pixiv encyclopedia about pixiv stamp (in Japanese)](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/pixiv%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97), their names are:

> - ハクゾウ（白い象の様な生き物）
>     *Hakuzou* (White elephant-y looking creature)
> - キツネ（キツネの様な生き物）
>     *Kitsune* (Fox-y looking creature)
> - 萌え娘（各人物）
>     *Moe musume* (Persons)
> - どくろちゃん（ドクロに角が生えたキャラ）
>     *Dokuro-chan* (A skull with horn)

The encyclopedia entry for [*moe musume* (in Japanese)](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E8%90%8C%E3%81%88%E5%A8%98) also mentions 4 characters, but they are nameless:

> - ピンク髪でツインテールの子
>     Pink twintail girl
>
>   [image: スタンプ子さん by 暫]
>     <sup>[スタンプ子さん by 暫](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=42116721)</sup>
> - 茶色い短髪の、スタンプではガッツポーズをしている子
>     [<s>Yasuna Oribe</s>](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=41491655) Short, brown hair girl guts-posing
>
>   [image: スタンプ娘 by Mukka]
>     <sup>[スタンプ娘 by Mukka](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=45558965)</sup>
> - 少し髪が赤っぽく、スタンプではドーナツを持っている子
>     Red-y hair girl holding a donut
>
>   [image: スタンプ娘 by miyabi]
>     <sup>[スタンプ娘 by miyabi](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=43142425)</sup>
> - 黒髪で、眼鏡をかけている子
>     [<s>Homura Akemi</s>](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=42499430) Black hair girl wearing glasses

---

**However, pixiv had a collaboration with pixiv's own ongoing manga *Gaikotsu Shotenin Honda-san*** which got adapted into an anime series, by releasing 10 time-limited stickers that can be used until January 31, 2019.

> [image: "Gaikotsu Shotenin Honda-san" stickers]
>
> <sup>[Gaikotsu Shotenin Honda-san stickers are now available on pixiv!](https://www.pixiv.net/info.php?id=4838)</sup>

Comment: yea that girl really look like Yasuna Oribe. Even her uniform is similar. I always got the feeling I've seen her somewhere before

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the stickers do not come from anime, although I agree they certainly have an anime "feel". A professional site would be very foolish to use copyrighted material without permission.

Possible sources for the artwork would be from their own staff (including contractors and subscribers), public domain image repositories, and sites such as [Deviant Art](https://www.deviantart.com/). For the latter, they would need permission from the individual artists, but many of them would be happy to give it in exchange for credit somewhere at the Pixiv site.